# User calling REST APIs on behalf of a different user

Tags: rest, api, api-design, scalability

Here's an example:

```
GET /posts
POST /posts
GET /posts/{post_id}
PUT /posts/{post_id}
```

This api is being used by SUPER_ADMIN as well as CONTENT_WRITERS. Its working great. If user is logged in as a SuperAdmin, he sees all the post, and if user is logged in as ContentWriter he sees only his post.

But, now the requirement is added, where SuperAdmin should be able to do CRUD opertations on behalf of any ContentWriter.

I added these APIs for that:

```
GET /user/{user_id}/posts
POST /user/{user_id}/posts
GET /user/{user_id}/posts/{post_id}
PUT /user/{user_id}/posts/{post_id}
```

Its working fine too. But the problem here is, **now there are too many APIs/Controllers to maintain**. Although, the controllers use the same service for that.

My question is, am I going to a right direction? Or is there any other best practices for this?

**UPDATE 1**

The idea here is somewhat similar to **impersonation**.

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me. doesnt post have a userid property?

Comment: I'd rather add a "on-behalf-of" when authenticating, artificially offering the same visibility rules as the user.

Comment: By `too many` are we speaking about thousands or just dozens of new methods? I do ask this because before re-factor something that it's proven to work (solving the problem) you have to find out whether the cost/benefits of a new solution outweighs (or not) the cost of the current one.

Comment: yes "too many" seems to be "the exact same number as before"

Comment: @laiv I feel like I'm violating the DRY principle, by duplicating controller file/code.

Comment: Controllers don't have any valuable/useful code to be re-used (these have no business). I would not consider DRY a duplicated Controller, POJO or DTO.  However, I agreed, it maight have a remarkable impact on the maintenance. That's why I asked how many new controllers are "too much".

Comment: **remarkable impact on the maintenance** this is the reason, my senior won't allow me to create multiple controllers for nested routes. So now I end up writing the code in the way as you suggested below (@Laiv). I think even this way the maintenance would be difficult, as the auth rules are now function specific, not the namespace.

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough details on the requirement. In my experience this is typically handled via impersonation, where the admin actually authenticates (through some admin mechanism) as the user and acts on their behalf. In that case all you would need to do is add the ability to impersonate users.

Comment: Impersonation is something completely new to me so wasn't able to mention it in my post. Although, I have added an update to the question. Will do some more research on that before adding anymore comments to this post. Thanks @DanWilson

Comment: Yeah, I second @DanWilson.  I wouldn't change much of the API.  However it is implemented, I've found that it's great to know both who made the request and who it should appear made the request.

Answer (score 3):

But as far as I can tell, what you are really trying to do is analogous to having Alice invoke

```
sudo -u bob ls /home/bob
```

I think you can reasonably argue one of two ways

First, that this is a *different resource*; it shares a common set of representations with `ls /home/bob`, but the authorization rules are different.  On the web, that would mean two different identifiers

```
/home/bob
/su/bob/home/bob
```

In effect, we have a new protocol, so we create new resources to support that protocol.

The other argument is that these are the *same* resource, and the difference between the two cases is the [Authorization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header.  That feels right? but I can't find any examples that do this.

You can find some examples where people have implemented a similar idea using custom http headers.  For example https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jira-rest-api-user-impersonation-marjan-sterjev/

Because of the lack of clear precedent, I would recommend continuing with the first approach.

Comment: Is there a specific downside to creating a custom header?  Standards are great but I'm not sure it makes sense to create a parallel API because there isn't an existing one to support your need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert at this, but since you are trying to make requests on another users behalf, from the APIs point of view the requests come from that user, not from the Admin.

Have you considered adding an admin route that allows the admin user to obtain a session token for another user? That will allow the admin to send the requests to the endpoints you already have using that other users token.

Comment: but in that way, I won't be able to track which admin did the change. I have to track that as well, since there are multiple super_admins

Comment: then you can have 2 tokens sent via headers in the http request.  One  for the user making the reques and another for the user on whos behalf the request is being made. Use the same auth mechanism on both to id the users. It goes without saying that a middleware of somesort is needed to ensure that the user that is making the request doesnt have higher priviliges then the user on whos behalf the request is made.

Comment: sorry i ment lower priviliges

Comment: I like this concept. I will see if I can achieve this. And get back to you. Thanks @Alexander

Answer (score 2):

A requirement to allow admins to impersonate users shouldn't require any more API endpoints than already exist in the system. This should be handled with additional form fields on your create/edit POST/PUTs rather than entirely different endpoints. You would need to add some validation that these fields are only populated when the request comes from an admin, or to ignore them for non admins. You should already have the authorization mechanism in place to recognize an admin request from a non admin, this functionality can be viewed as a slight extension to that. While not required for fulfilling the business need, it would also be a good idea to modify your database/persistence layer to track both who made an update and who should be displayed as an update. This will prove useful should an admin abuse their power.

Comment: so are you insisting on sending user_id as a request parameter in the payload?

Comment: @TheManish the user_Id of the impersonated user should be in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

I think a key thing will be your exact requirements around what it means to "post on behalf of another user"

But, assuming its just the author byline I would simply have a property on the Post object

```
class Post
{
    public string AuthoredByUserId {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

Now in your controller you can check whether AuthoredByUserId is the same as the user submitting the post and either allow it for super users or disallow it from normal users.

Having said that, personally I would *still* add a seperate endpoint simply so I can use built in authentication per endpoint methods, rather than having to code an authentication check eg.

```
[Authorise(Roles="ContentWriter")]
public Action AddPost(Post)
{
    ...error if AuthoredByUserId != the users Id
}

[Authorise(Roles="SUPER_ADMIN")]
public Action AddPostForAnotherUser(Post)
{
    ..ignore the userid validation
}
```